# Best system test technique for new front end to legacy system

Tags: oracle, testng

Aplogies in advance for asking a rather vague question ...

I need to test a new front end to a database. problems are 1) the db schema is huge with no documentation and b) there are many downstream systems - too many to build in test environment.

I was wondering if this appraoch may add value - 1) execute the same operations with a)new and then b) old frontend system (recording times when started / finished) then 2) Use LogMiner to query the redo log (using start and end times) and compare the changes to the db during a) and b).

Are there better appraches?

Matt

Comment: The use of LogMiner for testing seems a meritorious approach to me! NB the `V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS` also has a `USERNAME` column which you could also use to differentiate between the old and new code -- assuming you can make each log in with different credentials. For east of testing, can you instrument your code to log the start and end time of the operations you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

When testing, you need to define a successful test before you start.  Meaning, you need to know what the end result should be based on your starting environment, your ending environment and actions you perform.  Example:  let's say you have an accounting system and you want to "test" a payment transaction from account X to account Y.  When you start, you know the balance of X and Y.  You run your test and send a $100 payment from X to Y.  After the test, is X = X-100 and Y = Y+100?

In your case, I would:

1) Take a backup of the database.  IE: start with a known, consistent state.

2) Run old processes.

3) Run reports on results.

4) Restore database from #1

5) Run new processes

6) Run reports

7) Compare reports from steps #3 and #6 and compare